# Loop. Why it can see only 10 from whole list?

Tags: python

```
def new_list(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i%10 == 0:
            return i
        else:
            return False
        
print(new_list([10, 20.0, 25, 30, 40, 98]))
```

i want to see all numbers from the list that can be divided into 10

Comment: Don't `return` at the first item where your condition is true - then the function ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done with a list comprehension:

```
def new_list(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x % 10 == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `return` in a function ends execution of the function. So either way, the your function will stop running after the first iteration in your `for` loop. I don't know what you are expecting for output, but in your function you can instead append the items to a list and return the list at the end:

```
def new_list(lst):
   result_list = []
   for i in lst:
      if i%10 == 0:
         result_list.append(i)
   return result_list
```